# Is it possible to get all services from an OSGi framework, without using service references?

Tags: java, lua, osgi

I am writing a lua script,which is supposed to get a benchmarking service from an OSGi framework. I have managed to get to the point where I have an object of type userdata, which corresponds to a ServiceReference; the thing is I cannot use getService from the Bundle Context with a userdata object. 
It yields the following error:

org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference expected, got userdata

So thinking around this I suppose I could bypass it by directly getting all services from the framework, then iterating over them somehow. Is this possible? Normally, references are a must in the OSGi when getting services.

Either that, or a way to pass the userdata object to the getService(reference) method.

**My code is:**

```
refs = osgilib.bc():getServiceReferences("CLASSNAME", nil);

if (type(elem) == "table") then

print(pairs(refs));

for ref in refs do 

collector = osgilib.bc().getService(ref); //The code crashes here

print(collector.getName());

end

else

print(refs);

collector = osgilib.bc():getService(refs); //The code crashes here

print(collector);

end
```

bc is the Bundle Context from the OSGi Java framework.
Thank you :)

Comment: What version of lua is this? I would (naively) assume that the result of calling `getServiceReferences` would be actual reference objects but your code would seem to indicate otherwise. That would seem to be a binding/library problem to me. Does `osgilib` have documentation that could help here?

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)
I think the problem lies in the osgilib.It is vaguely documented, but from what I see it only casts the context, not the subsequent calls to it, to the proper type. I will see what I can learn about this.
Concerning Lua, the version on my computer is 5.1.5.

Comment: lua 5.1.5 shouldn't allow `for ref in refs do` to work at all that's why I asked. That's a lua 5.0 construct as I recall (implicit `pairs` on a table).

Comment: Turns out that we had to do an additional line of a local variable in the code:

     for i=1,refs.length do
      local ref = refs[i];
      local serv = osgilib.bc():getService(ref);
      print(serv:getName());
     end

I guess that the osgilib Lua version is different from the one on my computer,then :) it runs without problem now.

Comment: If you solved the problem you should write the solution up as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Can you explain how you run LUA on OSGi? I tried to google `osgilib lua` but did not get any relevant hits?